# How to Efficiently by Time generate random unique temp File Name for storing in Custom Directory?

Tags: php, unique, filenames

**The structure need to be**

- /custom-dir/file-1.txt
- /custom-dir/file-2.txt
  ...

File name is not neccesary to be file-1.txt, file-2.txt.

Only requirenment - files need to be unique and has **.txt** extension.

**Theoretically these files names could be**

- /custom-dir/random.txt
- /custom-dir/42.txt
  ...

**The solution I've found myself**

```
function generate_file_name() {
    $file_index = 0;
    do {
        $file_index++;
        $file = "custom-dir/file-$file_index";
    } while( file_exists( $file ) );

    return $file;
}
```

The function `generate_file_name()` is being called via **REST POST** request.
With new uploaded files.

But the problem is - with every request needs to start from stratch checking.

From 1 to max available file name.

And every request does 20 000+ iteration. Every time.
Currently there is 20 000+ files.

How to complete this by efficient way with minimum amount of iteration.
Without checking all of these files from 1 to N every time?

Comment: Put the generated file names in a database and check the database each time a file is created.

Comment: Or you might scan the PHP Manual and find the function  [tempnam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, What I would do is split the original filename from the the extension

```
<?php 

$fileExt = explode('.', $filename);

$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
```

And then generate a unique file name as below and then append the extension

```
 $fileNameNew = date('Ymdhis',time()).mt_rand().".".$fileActualExt; //current date with hour, minutes and exact seconds + time + random digits
?>
```

Hoping you find this useful